# Where can I get books written by Brahmananda Saraswati?

Tags: yoga, book-recommendation

[Brahmananda Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmananda_Saraswati) was the pontiff of jyotir math of Uttarakhand. He had taught yoga to famous personalities like Mahesh Yogi.

which are the books written by him?

where can I download or purchase these ?

Comment: Please check this [google link](https://www.google.co.in/search?sa=X&q=brahmananda+saraswati+books&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MDUwtDBWQjC1pLKTrfST8vOz9RNLSzLyi6xA7GKF_LycykeMwdwCL3_cE5bymrTm5DVGFy48ioXUuNhc80oySyqFZLh4pRA2aDBIcXMhuDwA9UIgNIoAAAA&npsic=0&ved=0ahUKEwir7p6PgNbVAhXIp48KHSXVDBcQ1i8IIDAQ)

Comment: Google search answering many questions :) Regarding books can refer this link: http://www.paulmason.info/gurudev/publications.htm & for download/purchase may check in Amazon or preferred stores:  https://www.ashramstore.com/home.php?cat=250 
 &  https://www.amazon.com/Books-Shri-Brahmananda-Sarasvati/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AShri%20Brahmananda%20Sarasvati